# How to assign value to current in linear linked list?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I tried to make a code where i assigned loyda and 24 as current's first and second member but when I run the program there is no loyda on output but rather thank the value I entered.  Can you explain this to me?
Note: the comment in the code is the given where i must put a valid c statement

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/*Create a node name TEMPLATE that contains your name 
(15 element array of char), age (int) and a pointer
to structure of the same structure type. */
struct TEMPLATE {
char name[15];
int age;
struct TEMPLATE *next;
};

int main()
{
//Create structure name HEAD, TAIL and CURRENT of type TEMPLATE. 
struct TEMPLATE *HEAD,*TAIL,*CURRENT; 
//Allocate memory location for CURRENT. 
CURRENT = (struct TEMPLATE*) malloc(sizeof(struct TEMPLATE));

CURRENT->name=="Loyda"; //Assign "Loyda" to the CURRENT 's first member 
CURRENT->age=24; //Assign 24 to CURRENT 's second member 

CURRENT->next=NULL; //Point CURRENT 's third member to NULL 
HEAD=CURRENT; //Point HEAD to CURRENT 
TAIL=CURRENT; //Point TAIL to CURRENT 

//Allocate memory location for CURRENT.
CURRENT = (struct TEMPLATE*) malloc(sizeof(struct TEMPLATE));
//Using scanf() function write a C-statement that will assign value to the 1st and 2nd members of CURRENT. 
scanf("%s%d",CURRENT->name,&CURRENT->age);


CURRENT->next=NULL; //Point CURRENT 's third member to NULL 
HEAD=CURRENT; //Point HEAD to CURRENT 
TAIL=CURRENT; //Point TAIL to CURRENT   

//Write C- statement that will display the value of 1st and 2nd member of HEAD 
printf("%s %d\n",HEAD->name,HEAD->age); 
//Write a C- statement that will display the value of 1st and 2nd member of TAIL 
printf("%s %d",TAIL->name,TAIL->age);

}
```

Comment: `CURRENT->name=="Loyda"` That is wrong for multiple reasons. `==` is the equality operator. `=` is the assignment operator. But what you really need is `strcpy(CURRENT->name, "Loyda")`. Suggest you review the chapter on strings in any C book or tutorial.

Comment: You completely overwrite HEAD and TAIL after `scanf` with the new CURRENT data. My guess is that the second (after scanf) assignment: `HEAD = CURRENT; //Point HEAD to CURRENT` is not needed.
Who gave these instructions in the comments? He/she should have given instructions on `free`-ing the memory as well.